# Is there an easier way to combine logic statements in excel sheets than the messy IF, OR, and AND statements?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I get the feeling that the real experts with other statistical tools will get a headache just out of the word "Excel," but I frequently have to manipulate spreadsheets on other people's machines for work. I used to just move things over to mySQL, but now I'm curious if I can't just stick to Excel and avoid the whole transfer fiasco.

That said, I frequently have to create logic statements for clients and using nested IF and OR statements is getting to be a pain in the behind. Can somebody suggest a cleaner methodology for a statement like the following?

```
=if(OR(A2="Validated";A2="Pending");if(B2>7,5;C3*4.5+if(rand()>0,5;randbetween(-10;10);0);C3)
```

Comment: For the example formula you've given (you're missing a close parenthesis BTW), nested IFs seem to be the best/only option. For operations on arrays, there are some shortcuts around using logical operators, but not for this type of "Return a if blah blah, return b otherwise" formula.

Comment: IF, OR, NOT, AND are the basic connectors of propositional logic, all connectors can be built from them. Determining whether an expression is true or false is trivial in propositional logic, and it also holds the distinction of being a system where either A or NOT A are true, and it can be proved, unlike most other logical systems we know. You should on to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the Power Pivot and Power Query Add-Ins. Together they can manipulate data and layer formulas on top of each other (avoiding the long tangled formula in your example).  The results can be delivered to Excel Tables or the Excel Data Model (a compressed format which can scale up to 150m+ rows).

Power Pivot:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel/download-power-pivot-HA101959985.aspx

Power Query:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=39379